# How to serve user uploaded images with Django on Heroku in production

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

In my website an user can upload images. This works fine in development when DEBUG=True, but if I set it to False, the images give error "Not found". I understand that the images disappear after 30 minutes of inactivity, but for me they aren't working at all.

I have Whitenoise installed on my settings.py middleware and on requirements.txt.
On settings.py I also have these lines:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And on urls.py I have this:

```
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The user uploads the files to an ImageField.

What do I have to change to make the user uploaded images also work on production? As the tile says, I'm deploying the project to Heroku.

Comment: Don't use heroku for saving image, because the image will go of if you deployed something new.So better use S3 storing static files.

Comment: I don't need to have them last more than about 15 minutes and not through deployments.

Comment: Heroku free dyno will go to sleep after 30 min, when the server is ideal.

Comment: I know, I just need to them last that little while so the user can see them uploaded for their short session.

Comment: For that you need to buy dyno.